# Get Schema Registry URL from Connect properties

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-connect

How to get the schema registry url from the connect properties with in a connector ?

I like to access this schema url with in my connector to get schema based on an ID.

Yes , i can explicitly pass schema.url as a property in my connector. But is there other way to get it automatically in the connector from connect proeprties ?

Thank You,

Comment: Maybe you can share your motivation for wanting to do this. Typically you would not be interested to dynamically discover a service like the schema registry.

Comment: @dawsaw . Assume that i am not gonna work with dynamic schemas in my connector. All my source schema is defined upfront and i have to just serialize my data and convert it to Connect Schema.